# How to move the remote x-window over SSH X tunnel, back to the remote linux host

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

Am connecting from my Linux (Mint) desktop to the Fedora (rpfr18) Raspberry Pi using SSH X tunneling.
When the Pi comes up, I connect to it from the desktop xterminal using:

> SSH -X root@192.168.x.y

Then I can start any x-window on the remote RPI like

> transmission-gtk &

Q-1) How do I move this X-window appearing on my desktop, back to the Pi (if possible). Like if I setup my transmission with what I want to download, but then want it to move back to the remote Xsession on the Pi where it should continue to run. If I close it here, then it exits on the Pi. Transmission btw, is just an example of a use-case, I am aware of it's web client, but to use that I still need transmission to be running on the Pi as a window (I think a daemon is also there however).

Q-2) At the moment I'm seeing this error which I don't know how to fix when I issue a:

> /etc/X11/xinit/Xsession

[image]

Don't have the HDMI cable to connect the Pi to my monitor to troubleshoot.

Q-3) I think the above is related to why vncviewer is drawing a window which is completely dark/blank at the moment.

> vncserver #remote rpi
>
> vncviewer 192.168.x.y:z #draws a dark/blank window.

So how do I fix these ? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in X. I know there were some works lately to make something like `screen` for X but that's to early.

You can run transmission-daemon instead, you'll have a web interface to all of your downloads whithout extra requirements like graphic libraries.

Comment: Yeah, had feared so. Any input on the other issues like why VNC/XStartx is showing that "Failed to load gnome session" windows ? Am sure that it comes up fine if you connect it to a monitor via HDMI.